# JTextArea not in line with the output of the console

Tags: java, swing, file, input, jtextarea

I have a question regarding the format in a `JTextArea`.

I read in a txt file.

The output format in the Eclipse console look pretty good.
But the output in the text area is bad.

How can that be?

```
public static void fill_up() {
    String datei = "/home/dirk/BMW/TEST.TXT";
    File file = new File(datei);
    
     if (!file.canRead() || !file.isFile())
            System.exit(0); 
     
     BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(datei), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
            String zeile;
            
            while ((zeile = in.readLine()) != null) {
                text1.append(zeile + "\n");
                System.out.println(zeile);           
            }
                   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null)
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
        } 
     
}
}
```

**Console Output**

[image]

**Text Area**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The output format in the Eclipse console look pretty good.
> But the output in the text area is bad.
>
> How can that be?

The Eclipse console (like most consoles) uses a monospaced `Font`. This allows each space character to be exactly the same width as each visible letter and aid alignment of the last column. Change the text area to use a monospaced font and it will align as expected.

Having said that, this task calls for a `JTable` - which is well suited to displaying tabular data.